# Attribute and Other Errors Found in My Python Code

Tags: python

I working with Python right now to build a space invaders project. The errors I'm currently facing is AttributeError: (ai_setting.screen_width, ai_setting.screen_height))  'Settings' object has no attribute 'screen_width' in Python. There's also an error around the "run_game()" part at the bottom. The game is so far supposed to draw a screen and place a ship image at the bottom center of the screen. Thanks!

```
import pygame  
from settings import Settings  
from ship import Ship  
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    pygame.init()

    ai_setting = Settings()


    #Creating the screen
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_setting.screen_width, ai_setting.screen_height))

    #Creating title
    pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invasion")

    ship = Ship(screen)


    #Creating the logo/icon
    icon = pygame.image.load("space-invaders.png")
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

    while True:
        gf.check_events()
        gf.update(ai_setting, screen,ship)


run_game()
```

Above: main.py file

```
class Settings():
    def _init__(self):
            self.screen_width = 800
            self.screen_height = 600
            self.bg_color = (0,255,0)
```

Above: settings.py file

```
import pygame
import sys

def check_events():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

def update(ai_settings, screen, ship):
    screen.fill(ai_setting.bg_color)
    ship.blitme
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Above: game_events.py file

```
import pygame

class Ship():
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen

        self.image = pygame.image.load("space-invaders.py")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Above: ship.py file

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the `Settings` class. You're missing an underscore in its `__init__`. You have:

```
def _init__(self):
```

when instead you should have:

```
def __init__(self):
```

Because of this typo, the `screen_width` and `screen_height` properties will not be created or set when `Settings()` is called.

Comment: Okay I fixed the typo. Now theres a name error of "screen.fill(ai_setting.bg_color)
NameError: name 'ai_setting' is not defined" and "run_game
    gf.update(ai_setting, screen, ship)"

Comment: @code Another typo. You passed it into the `update` function with the name `ai_settings`, but you're referring to it as `ai_setting` within that function. Either change `ai_setting` to `ai_settings` in `update`, or change the `ai_settings` parameter to `ai_setting`.